# WPF XAML custom control to look like an LED

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I wanted a control that looks like an LED and I found this code here
[WPF Custom LED Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855236/wpf-custom-led-checkbox)
The problem is I can't get it to change colors.  When I start typing the trigger OnColor or OffColor it says the member is not recognized.  Here's the Code

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfLed.LedControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfLed"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Style TargetType="local:LedControl">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LedControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="grd"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

                        <Ellipse x:Name="LedBorder" 
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                StrokeThickness="2"
                                Stretch="Uniform"/>

                        <Ellipse x:Name="CenterGlow" Stretch="Uniform">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="-0.25"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.91"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>

                        <Ellipse x:Name="CornerLight" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="2">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.15 0.15" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Grid>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="LedBorder" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=OnColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="LedBorder" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=OffColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CenterGlow" Property="Fill">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush Opacity="1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="-0.5" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#888"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's how I'm trying to use it

```
    <local:LedControl IsChecked="true" IsEnabled="true" OnColor="Green" x:Name="Led1" Content="Led1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Here's the C# code in the User Control

```
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Media;

    namespace WpfLed
    {
public partial class LedControl : UserControl
    {

        static LedControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LedControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LedControl)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OnColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("OnColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(LedControl), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Green));

        public Brush OnColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(OnColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OnColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OffColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("OffColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(LedControl), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red));

        public Brush OffColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(OffColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OffColorProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

}

I've even tried rebuilding the solution, I'm sure its something simple that I'm overlooking.

EDIT:
I put the template under User control I forgot to post the C# code to add the dependencies but it still doesn't recognize that control.  I updated the code above to reflect the changes.  I'm new to using WPF and XAML, I don't get any errors in the UserControl just when I try to use it in the MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Can you also who the "code behind"? In the question you reference I think  `OnColor` and `OffColor` are thought to be part of the code behind, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857924/3737186).

Comment: In the example they show the color change both code behind or XAML.  I was wanting to do both.  I didn't try doing it in C# yet because it wouldn't register in XAML.  I'll give it a shot and see if it works in C#

Answer (score 1):

The class CheckBox(the type, that is) doesn't have a Dependency Property named OnColor and OffColor.

You need to create a new class, inheriting from CheckBox, and add to it those 2 new Dep Props.

Or use AttachedProperty instead.

Comment: I forgot to post the C# code for the added dependencies, it's the same as the website that I linked too.