# Glowing effect in WPF

Tags: wpf, shader, hlsl

On a WPF application, I'm trying to apply a glowing effect to a `DrawingGroup` or to it's `DrawingContext`.

From what I could find out, there is not a built-in way to do it, the `BitmapEffect` of `DrawingGroup` is now obsolete, so we have to use the `Effect` property, on which there are just three options: `BlurEffect`, `DropShadowEffect` and `ShaderEffect`, which means that my only option is to use a custom `ShaderEffect` that involves making a DirectX shader in HLSL (on which I have no experience at all).

Here is an effect similar to what I want to achieve:

[image: Effect]

Is there any alternative to get something similar to this in WPF? or;

Is there any good resource for such HLSL effects? I found a bunch of HLSL effect libraries around but none had something similar to this.

Comment: maybe try gradient brushes? with transparent component? see example: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtlfK.png), [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857924/1506454)

Comment: oh nice, thanks for the suggestion @ASh, I'll try to do something similar then.