# How to make a CustomControl with a particular shape that inherits from the Button control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have created a `MenuBarButton.cs` CustomControl in which I inherit from the `Button` class to add an image and some text to the button like in the picture shown below.

[image]

Here's my control class:

```cs
public class MenuBarButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemName",             // Property name
            typeof(string),         // Property type
            typeof(MenuBarButton)   // Property owner
            );
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ItemNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Source",               // Property name
            typeof(ImageSource),    // Property type
            typeof(MenuBarButton)   // Property owner
            );
    public ImageSource Source
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
    static MenuBarButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MenuBarButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MenuBarButton))
            );
    }
}
```

And the Style is where I'm stuck a bit. So far I have this:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuBarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MenuBarButton}">
                <Button>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ItemName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But ideally I'd like to define a custom shape for the button while keeping the rest of the functionalities such as hovering over and pressing the button. I really wanted to do this with a custom control cause I got tired of having to create a buttons with an `Image` and a `TextBlock` inside over and over.

Do I have to define a separate style for the Button's shape explicitly or is there a way I can do this inside of the MenuBarButtonStyle dictionary?

Comment: `Template` property is the correct place to define a custom shape. However it doesn't make sense to put Button in template for custom Button. Custom button will be clickable without it. Use Border instead with necessary background. [Here is an example with custom CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857924/1506454) (which is also ButtonBase)

Comment: So because I have inherited from `Button` in the code-behind, the MenuBarButtonStyle will immediately affect the appearance of the resulting button?

Comment: It will look according to Template no mater what is the base class. you have `<Button>` in Template so it looks like default Button. if you need colored circle - use Border with CornerRadius, or Ellipse like in example.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a shot as is, thanks!

Comment: hi @ASh, I'd like to add an attached property to my custom control, for example: MenuBarButton.Text to define the text, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: you don't need *attached* DP. just regular DP - same as ItemName

Comment: how about making the text stylable separately? such as MenuBarButton.Text.Fontsize or ~.Foreground etc

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the default template for the `Button` and then edit as per your requirements. The easiest way to do this would be add a `<Button />` element to a XAML source file in Visual Studio, switch to design mode, right-click on the `Button` and choose `Edit Template` and then `Edit a copy ...`.

You could then for example replace the `Border` element in the default template with an `Ellipse`.

Below is an example:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="border" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                 Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Content="Button..." />
```

**Appearance:**

[image]